# HDMI unplugging sound and display bug

Tags: settings, sound

Well as I plugged in the monitor to my laptop it all run smoothly. Then I turned off my built-in display from settings and chose sound output - same HDMI.
It worked well until I decided to turn my built-in display back. 
as I click on cogwheel and swipe "turn on display" it everytime suddenly returns back to previous position. =\ dat terrible bug T.T
Furthermore ElementaryOS saves settings for every separate display and after pluggin in HDMI again built-in display goes off and same can't be turned on via "settings".
I guess there exists kind of a pure black terminal magic to turn it all but in "settings" there is definitely a bug.

Sound:
If I don't switch sound output back to my built-in speakers some strange things are goin to happen:
system sounds and sound from firefox are working well. But all the other applications give no sound. I had to plug HDMI again and in sound settings explicitly switch sound output to built-in speakers. Nothing else {  including reboot} didn't help me.

Best wishes, 
Amphyby.